Accessing a pointer stored in memory without loading it into a register
arch i386; syntax GAS
I have a pointer variable called active, to which I have tried to copy a register value in assembly. I have found out pretty quickly that movl %esp, (active) did not set the value pointed by active, but instead it set active itself. After some google searching and head scratching I have come to try this approach: movl active, %eax; movl %esp, (%eax) which worked fine, but not in the way I wanted it. This code executes at a point where I should not change any register nor mess with the stack, so that loading a register straight to a memory location stored in memory (variable) would help a lot.
Why can't I access a pointer variable directly (or can I?) and have to load it into a register first? Is there any workarounds?

That's how x86 ISA is designed. No way for double indirection. If you are allowed to temporarily modify a register, you can xchg twice.

@Jester xchg is a great alternative. Thanks a lot!

xchg requires (active) to be writable (which seems to be the case for you). But overall, this smells a bit like an XY problem, IMO.

The correct solution: free a register into which you can load the pointer, then use that register to access the pointee.

Not only does xchg require active to be writeable, it is also not thread-safe (if anything else accesses active in the mean-time), and is also slow (because xchg with memory is an atomic operation - it implies a lock prefix). You'd probably be better off finding/creating another scratch variable in memory and mov-ing a register in there and then back out.

@fuz It is indeed the ideal approach most of the time, but as I mentioned above, this code executes at a sticky situation where I should not override any register nor mess with the stack (at least not in a way I could not restore).

Well if you can mess with the stack then of course you can do push %eax; mov active, %eax; mov %esp, (%eax); addl $4, (%eax); pop %eax
